# LiveChatTranscript get record from flow: Error: sObject type 'LiveChatTranscript' is not supported

Tags: service-cloud-console, visual-flows, einstein-chatbot, livechattranscript

I have Autolaunched Flow, I am launching flow from the Einstien chatbot.
This issue started since last 5 days. Earlier it was working as expected. And there are no changes in OWD, Profile. OWD is

- Public read/write(Default Internal Access)
- Private(Default External Access)

And with these same sharing settings, this is working in Production, but the issue is in Sandbox.
Here is the issue: When I am starting Bot, the flow getting failed with the below error:

[image]

```
Find one LiveChatTranscript record where

Id Equals {!Routable_Id_Input} (5707d000000gW1fAAE)
Result

Info
Failed to find record.
Info
Error Occurred:

This error occurred when the flow tried to look up records: SELECT LiveChatButtonId, Id FROM LiveChatTranscript WHERE ((Id = ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:34 sObject type 'LiveChatTranscript' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.
```

Comment: Do you have the User perm: "Chat User"  enabled and [Einstein Reply Recommendations](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.reply_rec_enable.htm&type=5)

Comment: I would like to know if you were able to identify the problem?

Comment: @sfdev No, still not able to resolve this. 

Swetha, Your solution will not work for me. My chat is on a public website, and for the guest user, there is no permission called "Chat User".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by changing Basic bot user to Custom user having System Administrator profile.
I got the answer in trailhead forum and worked for me. You can try the same and check if it solve the issue in your scenario.

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000NQfDlSAL

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much @sfdev, you saved my day.

I am just adding this answer for those who are not familiar with Bot settings, as I had taken the time to find out the settings suggested by @SfDev.

Open the Einstein bot

-> Select the Overview from the Dropdown in the top left corner
[image]

-> Notice the box `"Bot user"` and update the

> "Bot performs action as" - Custom chatbot user (Recommended option)

And Select any user name with System Admin Profile, as attached in the screenshot:

[image]